# Python JSON schema validation for array of objects

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I am trying to validate a JSON file using the schema listed below, I can enter any additional fields, I don't understand, what I am doing wrong and why please?

**Sample JSON Data**

```
{
    "npcs":
    [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Pilot Alpha",
            "isNPC": true,
            "race": "1e",
            "testNotValid": false
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Pilot Beta",
            "isNPC": true,
            "race": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**JSON Schema**

I have set "required" and "additionalProperties" so I thought the validation would fail....

```
FileSchema = {
    "definitions":
    {
        "NpcEntry":
        {
            "properties":
            {
                "id": { "type": "integer" },
                "name": { "type" : "string" },
                "isNPC": { "type": "boolean" },
                "race": { "type" : "integer" }
            },
            "required": [ "id", "name", "isNPC", "race" ],
            "additionalProperties": False
        }
    },

    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "npcs" ],
    "additionalProperties": False,
    "properties": 
    {
        "npcs":
        {
            "type": "array",
            "npcs": { "$ref": "#/definitions/NpcEntry" }
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON file and schema are processed using the jsonschema package for Python, (I am using python 3.7 on a Mac).

The method I use to read and validate is below, I have removed a lot of the general validation to make the code as short and usable as possible:

```
import json
import jsonschema

def _ReadJsonfile(self, filename, schemaSystem, fileType):

    with open(filename) as fileHandle:
        fileContents = fileHandle.read()
 
    jsonData = json.loads(fileContents)

    try:
        jsonschema.validate(instance=jsonData, schema=schemaSystem)

    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as ex:
        print(f"JSON schema validation failed for file '{filename}'")
        return None

    return jsonData
```

Comment: what is your question? you didnt mention any?

Comment: Question is: Why doesn't it work and why please

Comment: _Question is: Why doesn't it work and why please_ That's quite broad/vague. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: @AMC I really don't know how you 'debug' it?  I have scanned through https://json-schema.org/. I was hoping it was some syntax or something I didn't understand/comprehend

Comment: @PaulMorriss _I really don't know how you 'debug' it?_ I meant debug the program. I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: @AMC I have a very limited debugged scope as jsonschema.validate() is a call to a python library and therefore compiled code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at: `"npcs": { "$ref": "#/definitions/NpcEntry" }`

change "npcs" to "items". `npcs` is not a valid keyword so it is ignored. The only validation that is happening is at the top level, verifying that the data is an object and that the one property is an array.

Comment: Thank you, me suffering code blindness at it's worse.

Comment: We've all been there :)